# ListAdapter sharing

Tags: android

Can same adapter be safely shared among different `ListViews` or `GridViews` ?

And if so, can two different view be returned from `getView()` based on who is asking for that view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can same adapter be safely shared among different ListViews or GridViews ?

Yes. But why would you want to display the same information twice (once in a ListView and again in a GridView)?

> And if so, can two different view be returned from getView() based on who is asking for that view ?

Yes... You could override `getView()` and return different Views from `getItemViewType()` based on `getView()`'s parameter `ViewGroup parent`. But if the Views are so different why not use to different adapters?

Comment: Thanks, The exact scenario I'm dealing with is to give user an option to toggle between `ListView`, and `GridView` of same contents.

Comment: @wingman: IMHO, that would be simpler and safer to implement using two adapters working off of the same data model.

Comment: @wingman Ok, that makes sense. But I would simply pass a different layout to the appropriate ViewGroup with `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, list)` or `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list)`, since you should need to have **both** a ListView and a GridView in memory at the same time.

Comment: @Sam Yes, I'm using two `ArrayAdapter`'s, I've overridden `getView()` in both. Since the items shown are a bit complex and have their own layouts. As far to fill in data in these adapters, I'm adding same set of data objects to both of them. Update: works !